# Rails 3 - make every string of a certain regex to a javascript onmouseover with content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, string, helper

In my app I have a article and comment model. I implemented a reply-feature, so that a user can reply to another comment by simply putting the id of the comment they want to quote in the comment form like this: #26 (to quote comment with id 26). This all works fine, with the regex and reply to user_id attr:
extract from my comments_controller create action:

```
  if @comment.content.match(/(#([1-9]+))\s/)
  iteration_fragment = $2
  iteration_id = %Q{#{ iteration_fragment }}
  if @replied_to_comment = @article.comments.where(:iteration_id => iteration_id).first
    @comment.in_reply_to_user_id = @replied_to_comment.user_id
  end
  end
```

Now, without creating a new model, I just want to put a 'html helper layer' on top of my comment system, so that these fragments such as "#33" automatically are converted to a "#33" onmouseover link, showing the content of comment 33 onmouseover.  So I don't want bb code quoting, but rather be really minimalist.
Does anybody know, what I'm looking for and how it should be approached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word automatic makes me think that the only way you could do this is with jQuery..

```
$("input#your_selected_input").keyup(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val().match(/(#([1-9]+))\s/) {
    $matches = $this.val().match(/(#([1-9]+))\s/
    $this.parent().after($this.html().replace( $matches[0], $("<a/>").html()));
  }
});
```

That's the automatic part..

To make the page load with the content in Rails, it would be something like :

In your comment model

```
def special_sauce_text
   matches = content.match(/(#([1-9]+))\s/)
   magic_sauce_links = []
   new_content = content
   if matches.present?
     for match in matches do
       magic_sauce_link << link_to(match, match, :class => 'your-special-stuff')
       new_content.gsub(match, magic_sauce_link)
     end
   end
   return new_content
end
```

Then you apply it liberally with :

```
Comment.special_sauce_text
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! This looks very much like what I'm looking for. The code makes a lot of sense, but I'm unable to fix the following error: `undefined method `each' for #<MatchData "#1 " 1:"#1">` I tried playing with the code a bit, but without success. Any idea what might cause this no method error?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not even getting to work the jQuery in the first place. I made a `<div id="content">...</div>` around my comment's content, inserted the script on my article show page `$("input#content").keyup(function(){ [rest of code..]`, but nothing happens. Sorry for possibly making some quite obvious mistakes, I'm still rather new to rails

Comment: Hey rails_has_elegance. That match data error is referring to some sort of error regarding the regexp match you're performing. I didn't look much into it myself, but double check by throwing a `debugger` in your code to see what exactly its returning there. For the jquery question, again i apologize for my not so perfect code. But break the jQuery down piece by piece with Firebug console and be using `console.log('your variable' + your_variable);` for each section to find out where your jquery is broken *and why*. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, sound goods! I'll try to further look into that and the jQuery. And this really was no request for a fully working code. Your in depth answer was amazing already in the first place! Thank you again for your detailed help Trip!

Comment: I know, this is a bit late, but I just got back to this feature in my app, after studying a bit jquery and so on, and I'm wondering why you suggested a keyup function? Is that jquery code meant for my comment-form textarea? Or is it meant for my comment's content text div?

Comment: The keyup function came from your reference to something happening "immediately". So the rails part will happen on page load. And the jQuery part will check for every single keystroke, constantly looking for a match. That if it finds a match, it will try to perform the same method that your rails method would have taken care of on page laod.